# "Use of unassigned local variable" in a Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics

Use of Unassigned local variable 'model'. Is what error message I'm getting.  Its right where I say if (model == null).  I'm not sure why its giving me a compile time error there.. someone please help.

```
public static T TryGet<T>(string fileName) where T : new()
{
    T model;
    using (var storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storageFile))
        {
            if (stream.Length > 0)
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                model = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }
    }
    if (model == null)
    {
        model = new T();
    }
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the error states, you cannot use a local variable until the compiler can prove that it has been assigned a value.

In your case, if your `if` condition is false, the `model` variable is never assigned.

You can solve the problem by assigning it an initial valued first:

```
T model = default(T);
```

---

Note that if `T` is a struct type, `model == null` can never be true.

You should change your code to

```
using (var storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storageFile))
{
    if (stream.Length > 0)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, descriptive answer. Oh—and congratulations :-)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know what to assign until you tell it.

Instead of `T model;` use `T model = default(T);`

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx

edit: another option is to just move the new statement to before your deserialization block.  That way, you'll either have a new object or the deserialized object just as you have now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being a reference type.  Besides, `T` isn't a reference type.

Comment: @SLaks, I don't see anything in the post suggesting that `T` isn't a reference type.  The code as it is now will only work for a value type.  For reference types, he'll have to assign null, default, or a new object.

Comment: Unless you write `where T : class`, `T` isn't a reference type.

Comment: @JimSchubert: The same error will happen with value types and reference types.  Instance variables are automatically initialized, but local variables are not.

Comment: I know where you're coming from, T isn't constrained to a reference type, but his code and his error suggest he's using a reference type when he is calling this code.  Unless people regularly call values 'model' and I'm not aware of it? :D

Comment: Removed the 'reference type' remark, since the assumption is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

When working with local variables, they must always be assigned a value before being accessed.

The reason for this is because usually, when the developer omits initialization, he relies on the runtime to assign it its default value, but in the case he forgot, this can cause some unnecessary bugs.

In the case of working with generics, and not specifying whether you're expecting a `ReferenceType` or a `ValueType`, you cannot simply initialize it by assigning `null`. 
In this case you need to use the [`default` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This will initialize the variable to `null` for reference types, or assign `0` for numeric value types. For structs, it will initialize each member to its default.

In the example you posted, the comparison with `null` lets me assume this method might only be meant to be used with ReferenceTypes, if that is the case, it is best to also add the `class` constraint.

Comment: I think that in the CLR there might not be a well-defined value *until* set (and the C# compiler simply takes the route of making the coder do it instead of shoving in a `default(T)` somewhere) -- I believe seeing an SO post recently saying the variable "slot" *could be accessed* through some direct bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

Because `model` is a local variable, the compiler is giving you that error because it is only assigned in the if statement.  If the if statement condition is not true, `model` will not be assigned a value.  Try giving it a default value of `null` or add an else statement and assigning `model` inside it.

```
T model = null;
```

Local variables are not automatically initialized, but instance variables are.

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private T instanceVariable; // automatically initialized

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        T localVariable;  // not automatically initialized
    }
}
```